# Merging SQL columns only for specific rows in the output

Tags: sql, merge

Just wondered if anyone could help with this? I am creating some xls reports in Quality Center v9.

With the rollup I have sub totals based on 'cy_cycle' column as well as an overall total.

**Query:** *Is it possible to merge columns 'cy_cycle' &  'cf_item_name' only  where these sub total rows for column 'cy_cycle' are displayed?*

I have tried to use case with concat etc but no luck so no doubt heading in the wrong direction and not sure if it can actually be done or not?

ps - there is a parameter - 'Report_Date'

```
Select nvl(cy_cycle, '# Total for ........ ' ) as "QC Test Set"*
,nvl(cf_item_name,'## DAILY TOTAL ##') as "Parent Folder"
,@Report_Date@  as "Report Date"
,count(TC_Status) as "Test Set Total"
,SUM(case when TC_Status = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Passed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Failed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Blocked' then 1 else 0 end) as "Blocked"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Not Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Not Completed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) as "Not Applicable"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'No Run' then 1 else 0 end) as "No Run"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'De-Scoped' then 1 else 0 end) as "De-Scoped"
From (TESTCYCL inner join CYCLE on tc_cycle_id=cy_cycle_id) inner join CYCL_FOLD on cy_folder_id=cf_item_id
Where cy_folder_id in(Select cf_item_id From CYCL_FOLD Where cf_item_path like 'AAAABBAAIAAE%')--**Pre-Pop Final_1**
and trunc(tc_exec_date) = trunc(to_date( @Report_Date@ ,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
group by rollup(cf_item_name, cy_cycle)
```

### Thanks in advance for any help :-)

thanks for the reply so far folks.

Ref DBMS - Its Oracle.

Prob wasn't clear in request - I was seeing if I could merge the columns 'qc_test_set' & 'Parent_folder' only for where those records in column 'qc_test_set' are null (where I have used nvl to give *'Total for ...'* BUT with out displaying any additional columns?
{eg in records 3,5,9 & 10 below column 1 & 2 would be merged/concatenated together}

Its obviously purely cosmetic and readable at the moment but was thinking if I can merge these I could then also right align for ease of reading.

(I have cut some records so overall total is out below)

```
QC Test Set         Parent Folder      Report Date  Test Set Total  Passed
-----------         -------------      -----------  -------- -----  ------
Branch              CR95               10-May-16    11          11
Business            CR95               10-May-16    5           5
# Total for ....    CR95               10-May-16    16          16
Issue 49            04 Misc            10-May-16    4           4
# Total for ....    04 Misc            10-May-16    4           4
Personal            01 Pre-Des         10-May-16    6           6
Personal            01 Pre-Des         10-May-16    2           2
Non-Personal        01 Pre-Des         10-May-16    2           2
# Total for ....    01 Pre-Des         10-May-16    10          10
# Total for ....    ## DAILY TOTAL ##  10-May-16    44          42
```

Comment: When you say 'merge columns', what do you mean?

Comment: Also, what DBMS is this?

Comment: Looks like Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by:

> only where these sub total rows for column 'cy_cycle' are displayed

If you happen to want to concatenate `cy_cycle` with `cf_item_name` everywhere where cy_cycle is not null, then `CASE` should work fine for you as so:

```
Select nvl(cy_cycle, '# Total for ........ ' ) as "QC Test Set"*
,nvl(cf_item_name,'## DAILY TOTAL ##') as "Parent Folder"
, CASE WHEN cy_cycle IS NULL THEN '' ELSE cy_cycle + cf_item_name END AS CycleItemMerge
,@Report_Date@  as "Report Date"
,count(TC_Status) as "Test Set Total"
,SUM(case when TC_Status = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Passed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Failed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Blocked' then 1 else 0 end) as "Blocked"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'Not Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Not Completed"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) as "Not Applicable"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'No Run' then 1 else 0 end) as "No Run"
,Sum(case when TC_Status = 'De-Scoped' then 1 else 0 end) as "De-Scoped"
From (TESTCYCL inner join CYCLE on tc_cycle_id=cy_cycle_id) inner join CYCL_FOLD on cy_folder_id=cf_item_id
Where cy_folder_id in(Select cf_item_id From CYCL_FOLD Where cf_item_path like 'AAAABBAAIAAE%')--**Pre-Pop Final_1**
and trunc(tc_exec_date) = trunc(to_date( @Report_Date@ ,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
group by rollup(cf_item_name, cy_cycle)
```

This assumes that `cy_cycle` & `cf_item_name` are both already string/character data-types (and thus, don't need to have a `CONVERT` or `TO_CHAR` in there with them).